# HighChart not getting data from server side?Error in parseJSON

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, charts, highcharts

I am getting a strange error while dealing with Highchart.

Its doing all fine with static data but really getting fuss while doing it from server side.

Code i am using,

```
function GetTab1() {
    debugger;
    $('#dvException').html('');
    $('#dvException').invisible();
    debugger;
    var apiUrl = '../api/Home/GetTab?dumy1=1';
    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                var Mychartdata = $.parseJSON(data);
                var chartdata = [['Firefox', 45], ['IE', 26], ['Safari', 8], ['Opera', 6], ['Others', 0]];
                // Radialize the colors
                Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
                    return {
                        radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                        stops: [
                                [0, color],
                                [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                            ]
                    };
                });

                // Build the chart
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'My Title'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                color: '#000000',
                                connectorColor: '#000000',
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.point.y;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Browser share',
                        data: Mychartdata
                    }]
                });

};

[HttpGet]
        public string GetTab(int dumy1)
        {
            string str = string.Empty;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = GetDataTableForPieChart();
            str = GetJson(dt);

            return str;
        }
private DataTable GetDataTableForPieChart()
        {
            DataTable nt = new DataTable("new table");
            nt.Columns.Add("key");
            nt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
            nt.Rows.Add("Firefox", 45.0);
            nt.Rows.Add("IE", 26.8);
            nt.Rows.Add("Safari", 8.5);
            nt.Rows.Add("Opera", 6.2);
            nt.Rows.Add("Others", 0.7);
            return nt;
        }

  public string GetJson(DataTable dt)
        {
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new

            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows =
              new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
        }
```

Get really confused ? Everything is working fine even getting data in proper format from server but chart is not creating ...but same doing all fine with static data ..

Comment: I get my error ..i am getting it for my column names ...now just to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the  GetJson method.Previously it was not serializing properly.Need to exclude column name for it.

```
public string GetJson(DataTable dt)
        {
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new

            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<object[]> obj = new List<object[]>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                obj.Add(dr.ItemArray);
            }
            return serializer.Serialize(obj);
        }
```